# JAVAFX::Can't insert values to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: java, sql, javafx

i am facing a problem related with SQL or i don't know,here is my Database Handler class, where i am connecting it:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends Configs{
    Connection dbCon;

    public Connection getDbCon() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost +":"
                +dbPort +"/"+dbName;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dbCon= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,dbUsername,dbPassword);
        return dbCon;

    }
    public void SignUpUser( String name, String surname, LocalDate date, String mobile,
                           String login, String password){
        String insert = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, dob, mobile,login, password)" +
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = getDbCon().prepareStatement(insert);
            statement.setString(1,name);
            statement.setString(2,surname);
            statement.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(date));
            statement.setString(4,mobile);
            statement.setString(5,login);
            statement.setString(6,password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this is my Controller class where i am doing actions with my button :

```
 @FXML
    void btnRegistration(ActionEvent event) {
        String login = txtLoginRegistration.getText();
        String name = txtNameRegistration.getText();
        String surname = txtSurnameRegistration.getText();
        LocalDate date = txtDateRegistration.getValue();
        String mobile = txtMobile.getText();
        String password = txtPasswordRegistration.getText();
        //Connect to DB
        DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler();
        handler.SignUpUser(name,surname,date,mobile,login,password);
```

Extending Coonfigs class , i have just declared the variables name of DB
There is no any error while compiling it , even i did all the operations with the Try and Catch , but anyway while checking my DB it is not inserted, I would be glad for any answers, Hope i did not regret you with my answer , if i did, i apologize.

Comment: what do you mean like java naming conventions

Comment: what happened when you typed _java naming conventions_ into your favorite seach engine? compare the rules you found with your code and fix to comply.

Comment: But what's wrong here with my question? what did you unlike here?
What did i do for you why un mark??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i just found my mistake
i just forget to put

```
            statement.executeUpdate();
```

At the end of the statements